# How does a nested yield work?

Tags: ruby, yield

I want to write a code that satisfies:

```
SomeClass.new.execute(method) == 3
```

and I have:

```
class SomeClass
  def execute(method)
    def method
     yield
    end
  end
end

method = 1+2
```

which gives me `nil`. I'm still very confused about yield. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're along the right lines, but your parameter `method` must be a code block.

You can create a code block in a few different ways. The most common is anonymously, using `{...}` or `do...end`. If you want to store the code block in a variable, which you'd need to do to call `SomeClass.new.execute(method)`, you can use `Proc.new`.

There are other ways of creating blocks (using the `lambda` syntax), but they are beyond the scope of this question.

This will work using a block stored in a variable:

```
class SomeClass
  def execute
    yield
  end
end

method = Proc.new { 1+2 }
SomeClass.new.execute(&method) # => 3
```

Or, more succinctly,

```
SomeClass.new.execute { 1 + 2 } # => 3
```

Comment: The first example is incorrect. It doesn't make sense to use `&block` with `yield` — `yield` expects a block, while `&block` takes any passed-in block and converts it into a Proc, which is quite unnecessary if you're using yield. And if you're going to directly pass in a Proc instead of a block, you don't even want the `&block` syntax, because there is no block to wrap.

Comment: Of course, thanks for pointing out. That will teach me for answering from (bad) memory. Edited.

Answer (score 4):

You're sort of in the right direction-ish. `yield` will execute a passed-in block. So you want to do something like this:

```
class SomeClass
  def execute
    yield
  end
end
```

And then you can call it like this:

```
SomeClass.new.execute { 1+2 }
```

Answer (score 4):

The `yield` keyword passes control to any *block* that was passed to the method. You haven't passed any blocks, so there's nothing to do.

You want something like this:

```
class C
  def execute
    yield    # Pass control to a block that was passed in.
             # Method returns whatever the value of evaluating `b` was.
  end
end
```

Now you can do:

```
C.new.execute { 1 + 2 }     # Pass block containing a statement "1 + 2".
# => 3                      # The result of evaluating "1 + 2" is
                            #   returned from the #execute method.
```

If you want to pass a *method object* corresponding to the block you want to pass, instead of specifying it anonymously, you can make a *lambda*:

```
b = lambda { 1 + 2 }
C.new.execute &b            # Pass an object to #execute that will be used as
# => 3                      #   the block.
```

Ruby has a few mostly-equivalent ways of making lambdas:

```
lambda { 1 + 2 }
Proc.new { 1 + 2 }
-> { 1 + 2 }
```

Comment: There is no point to the `&b` in the first example.

Comment: Ways of making lambdas are not equivalent. `Proc.new {}` will create `proc` instead of `lambda`.